How to Remove Grey Overlay on Selected Options in Microsoft Edge?
I'm working on a Vue.js project where I need to style the selected options in a multi-select dropdown. The dropdown is styled using Bootstrap classes. My goal is to apply specific styles (like bg-primary for selected options and badge-secondary for unselected ones). This works fine in most browsers, but in Microsoft Edge, a grey overlay is applied to the selected options, which overrides my custom styles.
Here is a simplified version of my code:
<div class="input-group">
  <div
    class="input-group-prepend d-flex"
    style="
      border-top-right-radius: 0;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    "
  >
    <span
      class="input-group-text"
      style="
        border-top-right-radius: 0;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
      "
    >
      <img src="./assets/tag.svg"
    /></span>
  </div>
  <select
    id="tags-select"
    multiple
    class="custom-select"
    v-model="selectedTags"
  >
    <option disabled value="" selected>Filter tags...</option>
    <option
      :class="{
        'badge bg-primary me-1':
          selectedTags.includes(tag),
        'badge bg-secondary me-1': !selectedTags.includes(tag),
      }"
      v-for="tag in allTags"
      :key="tag"
      :value="tag"
    >
      {{ tag }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>

When I select an element from the list, it is displayed in the correct color for a short time, but then quickly changes back to the gray overlay background.
Attempts to solve:

Created custom CSS classes to override the default styles
Attempted to use normalize.css to ensure consistent styling across browsers

Additional Information:

Browser: Microsoft Edge
Framework: Vue.js
CSS Library: Bootstrap

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

May I ask you to share your css?

It's been nothing special. I applied the background, background-color and color attributes to the option elements (with !important) but that changed nothing...
It seem like the overriden style only applies to the selected elements since the others get styled the way I want to.

set appearance: none at the start of your option elements.

Do you mean the selected option has a default grey background color in Edge? If there's any misunderstanding, please provide a minimal code snippet which can reproduce the issue. Is the behavior the same in Chrome?

yas, every browser has its own default inputs(e.g. select) styles. you have to first clear it by appearance: none, then your custom style
